# Send an email from Python Script

Tags: python, automation

I am trying to send an email from a python script. I am using this example but somehow the code keeps on running and does give back anything.

```
import smtplib

to = 'receiver'
gmail_user = 'username'
gmail_pwd = 'password'
smtpserver = smtplib.SMTP("smtp.gmail.com", 587)
smtpserver.ehlo()
smtpserver.starttls()
smtpserver.ehlo()
smtpserver.login(gmail_user, gmail_pwd)
header = 'To:' + to + '\n' + 'From: ' + gmail_user + '\n' + 'Subject:testing \n'
print header
msg = header + '\n this is test msg from mkyong.com \n\n'
smtpserver.sendmail(gmail_user, to, msg)
print 'done!'
smtpserver.close()
```

I also enabled the allow less secure apps in google account. The error I get on interrupting this code is :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/kgandh003c/PycharmProjects/kandarp_exercise/kandarp.py", line 6, in <module>
    smtpserver = smtplib.SMTP("smtp.gmail.com", 587)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/smtplib.py", line 256, in __init__
    (code, msg) = self.connect(host, port)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/smtplib.py", line 316, in connect
    self.sock = self._get_socket(host, port, self.timeout)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/smtplib.py", line 291, in _get_socket
    return socket.create_connection((host, port), timeout)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 575, in create_connection
    raise err
socket.error: [Errno 60] Operation timed out
```

Please let me know what could be wrong with this if anyone has faced this issue.

Thanks

Comment: Is there any configuration I'm not aware of ? I'm using El Capitan

Comment: Wow very cool script! I can confirm there's nothing wrong with your code since I ran it as-is, modifying only the 3 credentials at the top for my Gmail account, and it ran perfectly. Sorry I can't suggest any solutions, but at least I can confirm nothing is wrong with your code.

Comment: @downshift It ran perfectly at my home ISP. I guess there is a problem with my ISP at work. I think its blocking some sort of traffic.